# Compare columns but exclude specific pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write query to compare columns between two tables but to exclude specific pairs which point to the same thing but are written differently.

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NYSE |
| 2 | OTC |
| 3 | OTC |

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | New York Stock Exchange |
| 2 | NASDAQ |
| 3 | Over the Counter |

This means that I when I compare columns to see which pairs are different the only result that I will have is `ID 2 OTC - NASDAQ`. The rest should be excluded because `NYSE = New York Stock Exchange` and `OTC = Over the Counter`.
How can I do this?

Comment: HOw do you determine the relationship between NYSE and New York Stock Exchange? I *assume* you have a lookup table, so you could use that.

Comment: No, I still don't have such table. It is not created and I have no permissions to create such table

Comment: You're going to need one. For a human, sure, you could see that "NYSE" is an abbreviation of "New York Stock Exchange", however, for an RDBMS they are completely different strings that are barely anything alike.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu. I suppose I can create temp table but I am still not sure how I will exclude pairs

Comment: You could use a `NOT EXISTS` then, if you have a lookup table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*If* you have some kind of lookup table, you could use a `NOT EXISTS` to check the value isn't in the other table:

```sql
SELECT ST.[Name]
FROM dbo.SecondTable ST
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.LookupTable LT
                       JOIN dbo.FirstTable FT ON LT.FirstTableID = FT.ID
                  WHERE LT.SecondTableID = ST.ID);
```

Comment: Thank you! I will create  #tempLookUp table.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution is to create lookup table:

```
DECLARE @Table_1 TABLE 
(ID int NOT NULL, Name VARCHAR(50) NULL)

DECLARE @Table_2 TABLE 
(ID int NOT NULL, Name VARCHAR(50) NULL)

DECLARE @Table_LookUp TABLE 
(ShortName VARCHAR(50), Name VARCHAR(50) NULL)
```

Then insert data:

```
INSERT INTO @Table_1 (
    ID, Name
)
VALUES
  (1, 'NYSE')
, (2, 'OTC')
, (3, 'OTC')


INSERT INTO @Table_2 (
    ID, Name
)
VALUES
  (1, 'New York Stock Exchange')
, (2, 'NASDAQ')
, (3, 'Over the Counter')

INSERT INTO @Table_LookUp
(
    ShortName,
    Name
)
VALUES
(   'NYSE', -- ShortName - varchar(50)
    'New York Stock Exchange'  -- Name - varchar(50)
    )
, ('OTC', 'Over the Counter')
```

and the query should just check whether it does not exist in look up table:

```
SELECT * FROM @Table_2 AS t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * FROM @Table_LookUp AS lp
    INNER JOIN @Table_1 AS t1 ON t1.Name = lp.ShortName
        AND lp.Name IN (t2.Name)
)
```